# Apache sends corrupted header

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I have configured a basic virtual host just to be able to list a specific directory on the server. For the local files it’s working perfectly, but one of the folder listed at the root is a symlink to a folder outside DocumentRoot. The listing of the directories inside the symlink works fine as well, but if I try to download a file or view an image here comes the issue. The client (browser, curl, …) does’t see a response header, because it is malformed. Here’s an example:

```
 11:57:54 GMT
ETag: "352c59-5ce9f41529407"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3484761
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

So this malformed header is prepended to the file which corrupts the data. Any idea on how to make apache send a proper header?

**EDIT:** I tried with the official httpd Docker image, replacing the symlink by a docker volume in the container, and it lead to the exact same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer and explanation found here: [apache2 sends corrupt responses when using a cifs-share](https://serverfault.com/questions/1044724/apache2-sends-corrupt-responses-when-using-a-cifs-share)

**TL;DR**
Add `EnableMMAP off` to your *apache2.conf* file